# multiplying time and number to be used as total time in WAITFOR DELAY

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms

I want to use WAITFOR DELAY 'hh:mm:ss' but the time inside must be specific. There are 2 things I am multiplying:

1) the time value in that WAITFOR which will always be '00:00:05'

2) This is a number which will be used as a parameter e.g. @Count = 5.

What can I do to achieve this?

I tried the following code which doesn't work:

```
declare @Count int;
set @Count = 5;
@Count * WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'
```

I expect the output to be 00:00:25 for the above query but its an error saying:

```
Incorrect syntax near '@Count'
```

Please help.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
DECLARE @seconds INT, @count INT, @delay VARCHAR(8);

SET @count = 3;
SET @seconds = 5;
SET @delay = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(MILLISECOND, @seconds * @count * 1000, 0), 114);

WAITFOR DELAY @delay;
```